# Change sha1 password mysql and Cakephp log in

Tags: mysql, cakephp, sha1

I'm very new to CakePHP.
I've recently taken over a project that was built in CakePHP v 1.2.4.8284.
I'm trying to change the password for the login page.
There is only one user stored in a mysql database.

fields - id, username, password(varchar 40),  nacl(char(6), firstname, lastname

In phpAdmin, I've tried changing the password while using the SHA1 function, but that doesn't work.
I've even tried creating a new user, but the new user information will not work either.

I've narrowed it down to the `usercontroller` in the following if statement:

```
if ($results && $results['User']['password'] == sha1($results['User']['nacl'] . sha1($this->data['User']['password'])))
```

It looks like the password in the database should have `sha1(nacl field)` + `sha1(password field)`.
But it is all wrapped in a sha1.

I'm not sure how the encryption is working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the complete login function.

```
function login()
{
    $this->set('error', false);
    if ($this->Session->read('user'))
    {
        $this->redirect('/test-folder/');
    } else {
        $this->User->set($this->data);
        if ($this->data) {
            //$results = $this->User->findByUsername($this->data['User']['username']);
            $results = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('username' => $this->data['User']['username'])
            ));
            if ($results && $results['User']['password'] == sha1($results['User']['nacl'] . sha1($this->data['User']['password']))) {
                $this->Session->write('user', $this->data['User']['username']);
                $this->Session->write('admin', $results['User']['group']);
                $this->redirect('/test-folder/');
            } else {
                $this->set('error', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure the version is 0.2.9? Also: This is NOT how a login method should ever look like - please read and follow the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: CakePHP with version 0.2.9? amazing

Comment: use `echo Configure::version();` to display the version.

Comment: Using echo Configure:version() this was the result - 1.2.4.8284

Comment: Don't try to be cute. Call the salt "salt" not "NaCl".

Answer (score 1):

- Get the Security.salt in Config/core.php: 'securitysaltvalue'
- Take a password 'yourplainpassword'

  UPDATE user SET password = SHA1( CONCAT('securitysaltvalue', 'yourplainpassword')) WHERE id = 123

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you should be able to generate a new Password with these steps:

1) Generate a Password, for example "test123"

2) Get the id of the user you want to change the password for, for example 123

3) Execute this SQL in your phpMyAdmin (Replace my demo values!!!)

```
UPDATE user SET password = CONCAT( SHA1(nacl), SHA1("test123")) WHERE id = 123
```

And please make a complete DB dump on that table before any changes. And better yet, test on some development instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried the suggested code, but it still does not work.

Comment: I can't see more in your code. You might have more luck by inserting more debug output.

Comment: My approach would be to var_dump the contents of $result after your call to findByUsername and compare it to a var_dump of sha1($results['User']['nacl'] . sha1($this->data['User']['password']). And also var_dump $this->data['User']['password'].

Comment: When I run the query, the result is  0 row(s) affected. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I need much more info to help you. What are the contents of the row you want to change. What was the exact SQL you executed. Also see my previous tips on what to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the question before I saw your debug post.  I will try your debug suggestion. FYI, here is the exact SQL that I ran UPDATE users SET password = CONCAT( SHA1(nacl), SHA1("test")) WHERE id = 2  There are only 2 records in the database. The second is what I'm using to test. Thanks

Comment: Solved!! Ran the query. Ran the var_dump sha1($results['User']['nacl'] . sha1($this->data['User']['password']) placed that result in the password field. Thanks ToBe

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @StefanoDP works, but the table name is 'users', not 'user'. So the command should be:

```
UPDATE users SET password=SHA1(CONCAT('securitysaltvalue','yourplainpassword')) WHERE id=123;
```

Don't forget to add the semicolon at the end of the statement.